# How to select view in IndexedStack

Tags: dart, flutter

I can't seem to figure out how to select the displayed view for the IndexedStack class. There is an index value but it is final and can't bet set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be calling the `IndexedStack` constructor in the `build()` method of a `State`. Store the index you want in a mutable member variable of your `State`, e.g. `_index`, and use `_index` as the `index` constructor argument for the `IndexedStack`. To change the `_index` to a different value, e.g. `newIndex`, you can call `setState(() { _index = newIndex });` anywhere in your `State`.

Your call to [`setState`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) will notify Flutter that your `State` wants to rebuild itself. At the appropriate time, Flutter will call your `build()` method and the new value for `_index` will be used.

You can learn more about widgets and state in the [Flutter Widget Tour](https://flutter.io/widgets-intro/#changing-widgets-in-response-to-input).